# How to stop a variable from being destroyed on pressing F5 in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, variables, global-variables, scope

I have the following code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var m=0;
            function add() {
                m++;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="add();">click</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

But if I refresh the page then again the value of `m` starts from 0. How can I persist the value of `m` between each load of the page on a client machine?

Comment: Yup, that's what it's supposed to do. If you want it to stay available, you might want to look into localStorage. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage

Comment: You have just destroyed and recreated the page by pressing F5, what did you expect to happen?

Comment: i expect somebody`s help to stop redeclaration of variable

Comment: is there sessions in javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use cookies from javascript. check this link.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

here is the working code sample:

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script> 
var m=getCookie("m");
if(isNaN(m)) {
    m=0;
}
function add() 
{
    m++;
    alert(m);
    setCookie("m",m,86400);
} 

function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function getCookie(c_name)
{
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
{
    x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
    y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
    x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
    if (x==c_name)
    {
            return unescape(y);
        }
    }
}
</script> 
<body>
<button onclick="add();">click</button> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

One way is cookie

```
document.cookie = 'foo,bar'
```

Another way to do is use [localstorage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/)

```
localStorage.setItem('foo', 'bar');
localStorage.getItem('foo'); // return 'bar'
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is what js mean to do on browsers, don't fight it, live with it. If you want to store variables in browsers, use cookies or local-storage(html5) then.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to use:

1. setting cookies by your backend script.
2. use session in your backed script. eg session_start,$_SESSION in PHP
3. use localStorage , that will work only in HTML 5 supporting browsers though.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. The DOM and all the JS variables in your page get recreated on refresh. If you want to persist it you can either use [cookies](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) or [localstorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage) to persist it.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal that refreshing the page loads javascript functions again - use sessions or cookies to store variables like that.