# Using variables after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering if it is possible to keep some data even after refreshing the page. For example, I have values in my array and I don't want to lose them after refreshing the page.

Comment: If you add more information on your use case, we can better specify a solution for you.  All the answers below will work, but some solutions are better than others depending on the scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Cookies in javascript or the HTML5 localStorage,sessionStorage variable .

To use HTML5 LocalStorage, simply use it like variable preceded by localStorage.

```
localStorage.variable=['wrg','wg','wg'];
```

To use HTML5 sessionStorage, simply use it like variable preceded by sessionStorage.

```
sessionStorage.variable=['wrg','wg','wg'];
```

For more Info **[See Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7684299/how-to-stop-a-variable-from-being-destroyed-on-pressing-f5-in-javascript)**

Answer (score 2):

I have used [jStorage](https://github.com/andris9/jStorage) in the past for storing data, its uses HTML 5 local storage where available and falls back to other methods when needed.

```
$.jStorage.set(key, value, options)

value = $.jStorage.get(key)
value = $.jStorage.get(key, "default value")
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a trick w/ window.name in some browsers which allows to keep data even after refresh. Window name can store a json of your array.

```
window.name = "[JSON]";
```

BTW, Dojo implemented wrapper around window.name
[Dojo WindowName](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/07/22/windowname-transport/)

Answer (score 0):

Set a cookie with your values and request the cookie.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create Cookie and store in it $.cookie("SomeKey", 1);